# Convert date string into "mmm. d, yyyy" format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert string such as '2-12-2018' to Feb. 12, 2018. I have tried many things but still is not showing me the month in format mmm.

Comment: There are so many questions about this topic on SO. Please show the code you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: There are [*many, many questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+reformat+date+string) on this topic already. What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

As others pointed out, there are plenty of existing answers to similar questions, but <del>since *JavaScript dates relentlessly drive me batty*</del>**[*](//)** I figured I could use the practice...  So here's one solution:

```js
function mddyyyy_to_mmmdyyyy(s) {
  var s = s.split(/\D/),
    dt = new Date(s[2], s[0] - 1, s[1]);
  return dt.toLocaleString('en-CA', {
    month: 'short',
    day: 'numeric',
    year: 'numeric'
  });
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = mddyyyy_to_mmmdyyyy('2-12-2018');
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

---

- Here's a [**demo on Codepen**](https://codepen.io/ashleedawg/pen/QWWzbBJ?editors=1010).
- Here's **documentation** on [`.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_Compatibility) and [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [Date/time](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#Syntax) formats to use with `.toLocalString()`

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

```
var res = moment("2-12-2018").format("DD/MM/YYYY")

var now = moment(res).format('MMM. DD, YYYY');
```

Comment: A string in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` or `D-MM-YYYY`  is not a date format that should be used in the _constructor_ of `moment`  or `new Date`  because it is neither  ISO 8601  nor RFC 2822

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function that passes a string as parameter, which creates a Date object from the string, and then returns the formatted date as a string. Such as the below:

```
var formatDate = function(datestring){
    var dt = new Date(datestring); 
    var month = ['Jan' , 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    return (month[dt.getMonth()] + 
    ". " +  dt.getDate() +
    ", " +  dt.getFullYear());
}
```

Then you just call it passing any date string as parameter:

```
console.log(formatDate('02-12-2017'));
```

Comment: You should not add your own functions to prototypes like that. Also this question has been answered many, many, many times before. Do not answer but mark it as a duplicate instead.

Comment: The OP has a string, not a Date so modifying the Date prototype is unhelpful.

Answer (score -1):

```
function formatDate(date) {
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
var day = date.getDate();
var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();

return monthNames[monthIndex]+ '.' + day +   + ',' + year;
}
```